# Highlight Current Page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can I highlight the current WP page using this code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1&exclude=52'); ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Found in the (huge) [documentation for `wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages#Markup_and_styling_of_page_items):

> All list items (`li`) generated by `wp_list_pages()` are marked with the class `page_item`. When `wp_list_pages()` is called while displaying a Page, the list item for that Page is given the additional class `current_page_item`.

So use the `current_page_item` class.

Comment: (BTW, my answer is not meant to sound like RTFM.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try and pass it the `echo=0` parameter. It should return the HTML instead of printing it and you can process it to find the current page, apply the class and print the result. Not very clean, but if the normal behaviour doesn't work, it gives you a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS needed; change color to whatever you want:

```
#menu ul li a:active, #menu ul li.current_page_item a
{
color:#000;
}
```